# What's a pre-unitary (pre-u) matrix? And a pre-column-unitary (pre-c-u)?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Going over a math text I found the following:

[image]

And going a little further I found:

[image]

What's a pre-unitary (pre-u) matrix? And a pre-column-unitary (pre-c-u)?

Comment: The definitions are given right there in the text, although I should mention that I've never seen any of these terms before. The text says that a pre-unitary matrix is a nonzero square matrix whose columns are orthogonal, and that a pre-column-unitary matrix is a nonzero matrix, not necessarily square, whose columns are orthogonal.

Comment: Is there any relationship with unitary matrix http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitaryMatrix.html?

Comment: Yes. A unitary matrix can be defined as a square matrix whose columns are orthonormal rather than just orthogonal.

Comment: $p$ refers to rows or columns (when it says $p \le n$)?

Comment: It refers to columns. If $p > n$ then the columns can't be (nonzero and) orthogonal.